# Proving that languages are regular with pumping lemma

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

Hello can someone give me advice to proof the following language are regular or not regular

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { 1. } L_{1}=\{x y \mid x, y \in\{a, b\}^* \text { and } \#_{a}(x)=\#_b(y)\}} \\ {\text { 2. } L_{2}=\left\{x c y \mid x, y \in\{a, b\}^{*} \text { and } \#_{a}(x)=\#_b(y)\right\}}\end{array}
$$

I don't know how to start some advice would be nice.
Thanks

Comment: What is the notation $\#_a(x)$? Is it number of $a$'s in $x$?

Comment: If so, regular languages are characterised by DFA's which cannot "count". For this reason, I suspect you can use the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) to show that both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are not regular languages.

Comment: Yes it is. And how? Sorry but that's literally not my best subject. Any advice? So for L1 i have x has a amount of a and y b amount of b

Comment: Actually, it looks like number 1 is tricky and $L_1$ ends up being equal to just $\{ a, b \}^*$.  For any string of $a$ and $b$, if you count the total number $m$ of $b$'s and then take the first $m$ characters of the string as $x$ and the rest as $y$, it seems that you'll have $\#_a(x) = \#_b(y)$.  For example, $aababbabbb$ has 6 $b$'s, and so splitting $x := aababb$ and $y := abbb$, $\#_a(x) = \#_b(y) = 3$.

Comment: Still don't get the proof have to use pumping, so how do i proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language $L_2$ is not regular. If it was, its intersection with the regular language $a^*cb^*$ would be regular. But this intersection is $\{a^ncb^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}$, a language which is not regular (this can be easily proved by the pumping lemma or using Nerode's equivalence).

The language $L_1$ is equal to $\{a,b\}^*$ and hence is regular. It suffices to prove that every word $w$ can be written as $w = uv$ with $|u|_a = |v|_b$ (here I use the standard notation $|u|_a$ for the number of occurrences of $a$ in $u$).
Let $w =c_1 \dotsm c_n$, where each $c_i$ is a letter. Consider the function
$$
f(i) = |c_1 \dotsm c_i|_a - |c_{i+1} \dotsm c_n|_b
$$
One has $f(0) = -|w|_b  \leqslant 0$ and $f(n) = |w|_a \geqslant 0$. Furthermore, if $c_{i+1} = a$, then 
$$
f(i+1) = |c_1 \dotsm c_ia|_a - |c_{i+2} \dotsm c_n|_b = 1 + |c_1 \dotsm c_i|_a - |ac_{i+1} \dotsm c_n|_b = f(i) + 1
$$
Similarly, if $c_{i+1} = b$, then $f(i+1) = f(i)-1$. In other words, $f(i)$ goes from a non positive value to a non negative value by increments of $+1$ or $-1$. Therefore, it has to take at least once the value $0$, which gives for $w$ the wanted factorisation.

Comment: If $c_{i+1}=b$, then we also have $f(i+1)=f(i)+1$, not $f(i)-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$L_2$ is not regular.

Sketch of a proof by contradiction: Suppose it is regular. Let $p$ be the constant associated with the pumping lemma (# of states of a DFA which recognizes $L_2$). Consider the string $w=a^{p}cb^{p} \in L_2$. Divide $w=ijk$ such that $i=a^{p-1}, j=a$, and $k=cb^{p}$. The string $ij^{2}k=a^{p+1}cb^{p}$ is supposed to be in $L_2$ but it is clearly not - a contradiction.

$L_1$ is regular.

The strings in $L_1$ are of the form
$R=b^{*}(ab^{*})^{m}(a^{*}b)^{n}a^{*}$ where $m=n$. That expression is almost a regular expression except for the presence of the parameters $m$ and $n$.

If $m < n$, then $R=b^{*}(ab^{*})^{m}(a^{*}b)^{n-m}(a^{*}b)^{m}a^{*}$.
Let $R_1=b^{*}(ab^{*})^{m}, R_2=(a^{*}b)^{n-m}$, and $R_3=(a^{*}b)^{m}a^{*}$, so that $R=R_1R_2R_3$.

Let $w_i \in L(R_i)$, $1 \leq i \leq 3$.

Since $n-m>0$, $w_2 \neq \epsilon$.

(1) From the left end of $w_2$, move each letter into $w_1$ as long as it is a 
 $b$. This is equal to appending more $b$'s to $w_1$, a step which still keeps the modified $w_1$ into $L(R_1)$.

(2) From the right end of $w_2$, move each letter into $w_3$ as long as it is an 
 $a$. This is equal to prepending more $a$'s to $w_3$, a step which still keeps the modified $w_3$ into $L(R_3)$.

(3) If, during (1), we move all $n-m$ $b's$, then there's nothing left to do. The string $w_2$ is now empty. By the construction, the resulting string (which is still unmodified; we just viewed it differently) is still in $L(R)$.

(4) If, during (1), we encounter an $a$, then we know that at least one $b$ still exists in $w_2$, and it is at the right end of $w_2$. Move the $a$ into $w_1$ from the left end, while simultaneously moving the $b$ into $w_3$ from the right.

(5) Go back to (1).

Although a formal proof is required to show that the above process "turns" any string $w \in L(R)$, where $R=b^{*}(ab^{*})^{m}(a^{*}b)^{n}a^{*}$ with $m < n$ into a string belonging to a language where its regex has $m=n$, and although a similar proof is required for when $m \geq n$, it seems that $L(R) = L(R')$, where $R'=b^{*}(ab^{*})^{*}(a^{*}b)^{*}a^{*}$.

Do let me know if I missed something.

Comment: What excactly is w2? Though the first is not regular, (alone to the fact that i have to prove it with pumping lemma)

Comment: A string $w \in L(R)$, where $R=b^{*}(ab^{*})^{m}(a^{*}b)^{n}a^{*}$ with $m < n$ was taken, and was divided it into three parts $w=w_1w_2w_3$, according to the three regexes $R_1,R_2$, and $R_3$. If it is known before-hand that $L_1$ is not regular, then one needs to find a particular string or a particular format of strings which "emphasizes" its non-regularity. Then, such a string can be pumped to show that $L_1$ is not regular. I will see if I can dig a bit deeper.

Comment: Wait so we just assumed it is regular and tried to proof it. R1 to R3 are the conditions that a language has to meet such it is regular?

Comment: Not exactly. The process attempted to show that the strings in $L_1$ can be described by the expression $R=b^{*}(ab^{*})^{m}(a^{*}b)^{n}a^{*}$, where $m=n$. That expression is not a regular expression. But the attempt was to show that $L_1$ describes all and only the strings inside $L(R')$ where $R'=b^{*}(ab^{*})^{*}(a^{*}b)^{*}a^{*}$ because any string in $L(R')$ is also in $L_1$ by the 5-step process shown. More accurately, the process shows $L(R') \subseteq L_1$. And since $L_1$ places restriction on $L(R')$ by forcing $m=n$, $L_1 \subseteq L(R')$.

Comment: So because L(R') is a subset of L1 it is regular?

Comment: $L(R') \subseteq L_1$ and $L_1 \subseteq L(R') \implies L_1=L(R')$.

Comment: Actually $L_1 = \{a,b\}^*$. See my answer.